# How to make initializer list implicitly convert to the class?

Tags: c++, initializer-list

For example, I have a class

```
struct A
{
    A(int i, double d) {...}

private:
    int m_i;
    double m_d; 
};
```

and a function with an argument A

```
void f(A a);
```

And I can use initializer list to call the function

```
f( A{1, 3.14} );
```

How to make the following simple version also works?

```
f( {1, 3.14} );
```

Comment: Doing `A{...}` is not using an initializer list, it's [uniform initialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Uniform_initialization) and is the same as doing `A(...)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The call of the function with the initializer list will work. You should do nothing special.:)

The call would not be compiled if the constructor had function specifier `explicit`. In this case you have to use the previous call of the function

```
f( A{1, 3.14} );
```

using functional notation of casting the initializer list to an object of type A.

Comment: what if we have another overload of that function that accepts another object with same constructor  ? https://ideone.com/iN0uKW

Comment: @xyz  There will be an ambiguity.

Comment: yes I know,It's weird that even making one of the constructors explicit does not work  https://ideone.com/uFif5G

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple overload of a function which accept objects with same constructor and you want `f( {1, 3.14} );` call  one of them

It's possible with some meta programming

```
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

struct A{
     A(int ,double) {}
};

struct B{
     B(int ,double) {}
};

template<class T=A>
void f(T a,
       typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T,A>::value>::type* = 0 ){
    std::cout<<"In f(A a)\n";
}

void f(B b){std::cout<<"In f(B b)\n";}

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    f({1,2}); //It's not ambiguity anymore and calls f(B a)
    f(A{1,2});//call f(A a)
    f(B{1,2});//call f(B b)
    //f(2); error
}
```

[live](https://ideone.com/rLEnR8)